# Unable to get rid of the cancel button

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using search display controller, and in some cases i do not need the cancel button

yet in the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` setting `showsCancelButton` to `NO`, or `setShowsCancelButton:animated:`

does no work

what can i do to get rid of the button ?

Comment: Perhaps you are confused? showsCancelButton is a method on a UISearchBar, not a UISearchDisplayController (which is deprecated in iOS 8) or a UISearchController (available beginning in iOS8). Maybe you need to show some sample code.

Comment: Make sure you have the delegate set and just put showsCancelButton in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution in **Swift3** - we need to make **CustomSearchBar** without cancel button and then override the corresponding property in new **CustomSearchController**:

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

override func setShowsCancelButton(_ showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}}

class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {
lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
    [unowned self] in
    let customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
    return customSearchBar
    }()

override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get {
        return _searchBar
    }
}}
```

In MyViewController I initialize and configure searchController using this new custom subclass:

```
    var videoSearchController: UISearchController = ({
    // Display search results in a separate view controller
    //        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    //        let alternateController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "aTV") as! AlternateTableViewController
    //        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: alternateController)
    let controller = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. iceland)", comment: "")
    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    return controller
})()
```

And it works properly and smooth! :-)